# Regex or any string method

Tags: java, string

Hi I am trying to validate a string e.g.  AA2016MY and I want to validate that the string position from 3 to 6 is a numeric value.

How to do this is simple java way.

Comment: Looks like a year to me, not just a numeric value. What have you tried also?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use `substring` for the characters your want to check.

```
String str = "AA2016MY";
int year = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(3, 6+1)); // 6+1 for 6 inclusive
if (year > 1900 && year < 2100) ...
```

Comment: Yes I want to verify that it is a year

Comment: @Pradeep - You can put a try-catch around the `parseInt` to prevent a NumberFormatException, i.e. the substring isn't a number